# Why is data.table not sorting when j part empty and by= is provided

Tags: r, data.table

I'm slightly baffled as to why I get two different results with the following code.

```
DT <- data.table(x=1:6,
                 y=rnorm(6),
                 group=factor(c("A", "B", "C", "C", "B", "A")), 
                 sex=c("M", "M", "M", "F", "F", "F"))
```

When I run the following code

```
 DT[, .SD, by=group]
```

I get printed a *sorted* version of the data table. However, why wont the following code give me the same sorted and printed version? I get the data table in the original order of the rows

```
 DT[, , by=group]
```

I'm sure there is an implementation reason for the difference in output I just haven't been able to figure out why. Is it because the `by=` is not really evaluated when the `j` part is empty?

If I set the key (which I really should be doing when I want to sort the table) the data table itself obviously becomes sorted

```
setkey(DT, group)
DT
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's just the chosen behavior when `j` is blank; `by=` is designed for use with `j`. Also, if you simply want to sort the table, you can also use `setorder`

Comment: There's an FR somewhere to implement this. We just haven't gotten to it yet. It'd be nice to have it.

Comment: So it more a "that's just the way it is right now" than because it would break something?

Comment: I guess this is the issue; not sure: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1105

Comment: Why do you want to do this exactly? I don't see why `DT[order(group)]` nor `setkey(DT,group)` get the job done.

Comment: I don't particularly want to do it. I just felt that the syntax would be more consistent if the different calls I listed gave the same output, and I asked if there was a particular reason for the differences.